# HttpClient Sending but not receiving the request

Tags: c#, wpf, api

I have a client server app. Wpf - Web api I am having a bit of troubles as this is working on one machine but when I switch to another machine it doesn't.

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> Get()
    {
        var result = (IEnumerable<T>)null;

        //Gets to this line and does not throw exception
        var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(BaseApiAddress);

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            ThrowInvalidException(response);
        }
        var resultAsString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<T>>(resultAsString);
        return result;
    }
```

API method:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public virtual IEnumerable<T> Get()
    {
        var items = Repository.Get().ToArray();
        return items;
    }
```

and Repository:

```
    public IQueryable<T> Get()
    {
        return _context.Set<T>();
    }
```

I get to the api and it gets the data while debugging through the code it has the data and looks as if there it completes the method on the api. all of that said it never returns to the GetAsync method.

I have hit a brick wall here and really don't even know where to start looking from here. Any Suggestions would be very helpful.

Comment: Looks like a classic case of deadlock caused by the synchronization context. Try `var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(BaseApiAddress).ConfigureAwait(false);`

Comment: that was it! thank you so much!

Comment: Be careful, using configureAwait to fix the deadlock is a hack and won't work in every situation, it is better to just not block any async calls .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run under a synchronization context, you'll get a deadlock if:

- The caller waits synchronously on a task (for example, calling `task.Result`
- Inside of the task, you use `await`

The fix is to use `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to avoid posting the continuation on the synchronization context:

```
var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(BaseApiAddress).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Of course, as much as possible, you should avoid waiting synchronously on a task.

Comment: thank you, so what i did was remove wait MethodThatCallsApi().Wait(); thank you again